# Apache Camel - Array of key/pair lines to object

Tags: apache-camel, etl, txt

I have a TXT file with user data separated by blank lines

```
Name : Daniele
City : Genoa
Country : Italy

Name : Giada
City : Milan
Country : Italy
```

I'm trying to convert that in POJO and eventually in CSV.

My route at the moment is like :

```java
from("file://data/input")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n\r\n"))
    .to("direct:card");

from("direct:card")
    .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.KeyValue, User.class);


@Message(keyValuePairSeparator = ":", pairSeparator = "\n")
public class User {
    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 1)
    String name;
    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 2)
    String city;
    @KeyValuePairField(tag = 3)
    String country;
    .... getter / setter ...
}
```

But the KeyValue type of bindy expects key to be `int`. So i can't use it.

What could I use to reach my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BindyType.Csv` to unmarshall your input file as *csv* data:

```
from("direct:card")
    .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, User.class);
```

You should then update your target *POJO* mapping for a `@CsvRecord` one:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ":", crlf = "UNIX")
public class User {
    @DataField(pos = 1, trime = true)
    String name;
    @DataField(pos = 2, trime = true)
    String city;
    @DataField(pos = 3, trime = true)
    String country;
    // getter / setter...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think because it separate Name:User as field pos=1 and field pos=2. Field separator should be "\n" but then each field should be splitted again and take the second token

Comment: Sorry @DanieleRavizza, just realized the shape of your data is not *csv* structured. Is there any constraints on transforming it?